# How to invert a numpy histogram back to intensities

Tags: numpy

I'm wondering if there is a numpythonic way of inverting a histogram back to an intensity signal.

For example:

```
>>> A = np.array([7, 2, 1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 10])
>>> H, edge = np.histogram(A, bins=10, range=(0,10))

>>> np.sort(A)
[ 0  1  2  4  7  7  8 10]

>>> H
[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1]
>>> edge
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]
```

Is there a way to reconstruct the original `A` intensities using the `H` and `edge`? Of course, positional information will have been lost, but I'd just like to recover the intensities and relative number of occurrences.

I have this loopy way of doing it:

```
>>> reco = []
>>> for i, h in enumerate(H):
...    for _ in range(h):
...       reco.append(edge[i])
...
>>> reco
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 7.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
# I've done something wrong with the right-most histogram bin, but we can ignore that for now
```

For large histograms, the loopy way is inefficient. Is there a vectorized equivalent of what I did in the loop? (my gut says that `numpy.digitize` will be involved..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([7, 2, 1, 4, 0, 7, 8, 10])
counts, edges = np.histogram(A, bins=10, range=(0,10))

print(np.repeat(edges[:-1], counts))
# [ 0.  1.  2.  4.  7.  7.  8.  9.]
```

Obviously it's impossible to recover the exact position of a value within a bin, since you lose that information in the process of generating the histogram. You could either use the lower or upper bin edge (as in the example above), or you could use the center value, e.g.:

```
print(np.repeat((edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2., counts))
# [ 0.5  1.5  2.5  4.5  7.5  7.5  8.5  9.5]
```